# Setting window.location on a LinkButton's onClientClick from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton, onclientclick

Can't be this hard can it!? I just want to change window.location onclientclick of a linkbutton and set this from code behind.

```
lb.OnClientClick = "window.location = 'Contact.aspx'";
```

Not working, just reloads the current page.

```
lb.OnClientClick = "window.location = '" + Server.MapPath("Contact.aspx") + "'";
```

Seems to resolve the url correctly (the dev folder on my C drive) but is denying me access!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example of how to use dynamically:

```
if (status = "fun")
  HttpServerUtility.Transfer("fun.aspx");
else
  HttpServerUtility.Transfer("sad.aspx");
```

also this should work

```
lb.OnClientClick = "window.location = 'Contact.aspx'; return false;"
```

---

Original post:

If it is in the code behind just use Transfer

```
HttpServerUtility.Transfer("Contact.aspx");
```

and this will pass all the form information:

```
HttpServerUtility.Transfer("Contact.aspx",true);
```

MS also has good documentation on all your options [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3x8t37x.aspx)

Comment: I don't understand how I can use your suggestion in my code? I need a link button to navigate to another page when the user clicks on it. This page (or OnClientClick event) must be defined dynamically from my C# code behind.

Comment: @DanielMcNulty - I gave some more examples.